# Rabbitmq nodes not able to join cluster?

Tags: rabbitmq

Below are the commands executed and error stack:

> [root@DGTLSITTIBCO2 ~]# rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@DGTLSITTIBCO1
>   Clustering node rabbit@DGTLSITTIBCO2 with rabbit@DGTLSITTIBCO1 Error:
>   unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@DGTLSITTIBCO1'. Please
>   see diagnostics information and suggestions below.

Most common reasons for this are:

- Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection or firewall issues)
- CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)
- Target node is not running

In addition to the diagnostics info below:

- See the CLI, clustering and networking guides on [rabbitmq documentation](http://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html) to learn more
- Consult server logs on node `rabbit@DGTLSITTIBCO1`

## DIAGNOSTICS

> attempted to contact: [rabbit@DGTLSITTIBCO1]

rabbit@DGTLSITTIBCO1:

- connected to epmd (port 4369) on DGTLSITTIBCO1
- epmd reports node 'rabbit' uses port 25672 for inter-node and CLI tool traffic
- TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed
- TCP connection to remote host has timed out. Is the Erlang distribution using TLS?

**Current node details:**

- node name: rabbitmqcli57@DGTLSITTIBCO2
- effective user's home directory: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- Erlang cookie hash: ci1chJoiyrDKCLOj2TDxaA==

Answer (score 0):

Please see [my answer](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/rabbitmq-users/4SXIHEHhOvY/discussion) in the `rabbitmq-users` mailing list. In short, your Erlang cookies are most likely not synchronized.

---

Generally, it's not very helpful to paste an error into your message without any other information. The people helping out on this list like to know what version of RabbitMQ and Erlang you're using and on what operating system, and a description of what you're trying to do.

Anyway, in this case, your issue is one of the most commonly reported on this list. If you search for the string Error: unable to perform an operation on node, you'll see many replies with suggestions on how to fix your issue.

The RabbitMQ team also maintains documentation, including a troubleshooting document: https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting.html

You should also read the Clustering Guide, specifically this section: https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html#erlang-cookie